# Julia: copy method on Azure Fileshares fails - Stat(...).inode is always zero

Tags: azure, filesystems, julia

When copying data from `\\azurefileshare\a\1` to `\\azurefileshare\a\2` we get an error:

`'src' and 'dst' refer to the same file/dir`

After some investigation, it seems julia uses the `stat` command to determine if folders are identical by comparing the `stat(xxx).inode` and `stat(xxx).device`

[image]

However, the inode is always `0` for any Azure folders that we pass into `stat(foldername)`.

Questions:

1. Have we misconfigured our Azure file shares?
2. Is this a bug in the `stat()` implementation in julia?
3. Is the julia `inode` comparison logic flawed?

Much appreciated.

Comment: Also asked at https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/36749